# Maven property is not being resolved

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

We have two different maven project - 1. test1 which is multimodule 2. test2 which is also multimodule.
I am trying to use ${test.version} to test2 project pom with the property define version in test1 project but not able to access the property as its looking for the variable version when trying to look for 1.2.2-RELEASE using ${test.version} but the property is not resolving.

Error : **[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test2:test-core:jar:1.2.2-RELEASE: Failed to collect dependencies at com.test:common:jar:1.2.2-RELEASE: Failed to read artifact descriptor for dummy:common:jar:1.2.2-RELEASE: Could not find artifact dummy:pom:${test.version} in central**
[image]

Comment: That property `${version}` is not defined nor supported. If you like to use that please follow the instruction: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html also read to the end of the docs(very important!)

Comment: its dummy name i used - we are having different name

Comment: That does not change a thing. because you have to use `${revision}` or `${changelist}` or `${sha1}` nothing else will work! apart from that why not using the real names in the post... that would make it easier to help..

Answer (score 0):

Unless a variable is defined in your current Pom or parent Pom (all the way up to the super Pom) it is not available.

You should not define the variable in test1 but in the shared parent Pom.